# What is the 0x4b midi message?

Tags: midi, electronic-music

This comes up as an undefined meta message when using the mido library.

I have got varying results from google search including a copyright message, and also one stating its a 'unknown on/off off = 0 on = 127'

Anyone have any idea what it is?

Trying to write a piece of music generation software using MIDI. Not much knowledge about music theory.

Cheers

Comment: Can you provide a MIDI file containing this event?

Comment: From where do you get this message? If you're writing a _generator_, you shouldn't have to generate any messages you don't need or want? :)

Comment: @piiperiReinstateMonica yes I am writing a generator but I'm just trying to figure out what is important to keep and what is not important (as I'm using other midi files to generate my music)

Comment: Unknown meta messages should be ignored.

Answer (score 2):

It's unknown MIDI event indeed. I'm the author of [DryWetMIDI](https://github.com/melanchall/drywetmidi) library. Here you can see all standard events status bytes: https://github.com/melanchall/drywetmidi/blob/develop/DryWetMidi/Core/Events/Info/EventStatusBytes.cs.